# Cordova Admob Pro Plugin From FloatingHotPot showing only the Test Ads and What to delete from the code to show only Banner Ad?

Tags: cordova, plugins, admob

I have added the below script on my HTML page within Body tag. Though, I was looking to show only Banner Ad on my app and I added my real Admob App Ad code on this script; I found that the built apk is showing Test Ads from Admob on Bluestack. I used Android Studio to build the app while generating the Cordova Files via CLI.

Here are the exact script:

> ```
> <script>   // place our admob ad unit id here   var admobid = {};   if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
> admobid = { // for Android
>   banner: 'ca-app-pub-7964685388872167/7227221134', //my real admobid
>   interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/7563979554' //admob test id 
> };   } else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
> admobid = { // for iOS
>   banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/4806197152',
>   interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/7563979554'
> };   } else {
> admobid = { // for Windows Phone
>   banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/8878394753',
>   interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1355127956'
> };   }   function createSelectedBanner(){
> if(AdMob) AdMob.createBanner({
>   adId: admobid.banner,
>   overlap: $('#overlap').is(':checked'),
>   offsetTopBar: $('#offsetTopBar').is(':checked'),
>   adSize: $('#adSize').val(),
>   position: $('#adPosition').val(),
> });   }   function showBannerAtPosition(){
> if(AdMob) AdMob.showBanner( $('#adPosition').val() );   }   function onDeviceReady() {
> if (! AdMob) { alert( 'admob plugin not ready' ); return; }
> initAd();
> // display a banner at startup
> createSelectedBanner();   }   function initAd(){
> AdMob.setOptions({
>   // adSize: 'SMART_BANNER',
>   // width: integer, // valid when set adSize 'CUSTOM'
>   // height: integer, // valid when set adSize 'CUSTOM'
>   position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
>   // offsetTopBar: false, // avoid overlapped by status bar, for iOS7+
>   bgColor: 'black', // color name, or '#RRGGBB'
>   // x: integer,    // valid when set position to 0 / POS_XY
>   // y: integer,    // valid when set position to 0 / POS_XY
>   isTesting: true, // set to true, to receiving test ad for testing purpose
>   // autoShow: true // auto show interstitial ad when loaded, set to false if prepare/show
> });
> // new events, with variable to differentiate: adNetwork, adType, adEvent
> $(document).on('onAdFailLoad', function(e){
>   // when jquery used, it will hijack the event, so we have to get data from original event
>   if(typeof e.originalEvent !== 'undefined') e = e.originalEvent;
>   var data = e.detail || e.data || e;
>   alert('error: ' + data.error +
>       ', reason: ' + data.reason +
>       ', adNetwork:' + data.adNetwork +
>       ', adType:' + data.adType +
>       ', adEvent:' + data.adEvent); // adType: 'banner', 'interstitial', etc.
> });
> $(document).on('onAdLoaded', function(e){
> });
> $(document).on('onAdPresent', function(e){
> });
> $(document).on('onAdLeaveApp', function(e){
> });
> $(document).on('onAdDismiss', function(e){
> });
> $('#btn_create').click(createSelectedBanner);
> $('#btn_remove').click(function(){
>   AdMob.removeBanner();
> });
> $('#btn_show').click(showBannerAtPosition);
> $('#btn_hide').click(function(){
>   AdMob.hideBanner();
> });
> // create a banner on startup
> createSelectedBanner();
> // test interstitial ad
> $('#btn_prepare').click(function(){
>   AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
>     adId:admobid.interstitial,
>     autoShow: $('#autoshow').is(':checked'),
>   });
> });
> $('#btn_showfull').click(function(){
>   AdMob.showInterstitial();
> });
> // test case for #256, https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/issues/256
> $(document).on('backbutton', function(){
>   if(window.confirm('Are you sure to quit?')) navigator.app.exitApp();
> });
> // test case #283, https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/issues/283
> $(document).on('resume', function(){
>   AdMob.showInterstitial();
> });   }   // test the webview resized properly   $(window).resize(function(){
> $('#textinfo').html('web view: ' + $(window).width() + " x " + $(window).height());   });   $(document).ready(function(){
> // on mobile device, we must wait the 'deviceready' event fired by cordova
> if(/(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
>   document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
> } else {
>   onDeviceReady();
> }   }); </script>
> ```

So 1: Can you please help me solving this issue? How to show my real ads from Admob on my app rather than this test ad from admob?

2: How to delete the Irrestritial and other type of Ad Code from this script by keeping the Banner Code intact?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now -  `isTesting: true;` due to which it's showing test ads.

set it to false, ti will show real ads.